# iPhone:- How to send push notification to specific Phone number

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, message

I have used these methods in my app delegate file and I'm able to activate notification service on my iphone but my issue is that, as I wants to send alarm to my friends iphone when ever I want so. For that, I want to use push notification that automatically update the alarm time and message in his phone.

---

```
    //in did finishlaunching

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken1 { 

    NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken1];
    NSLog(@"device......%@",str);

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(@"device......%@",str);    

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    

}
```

Comment: That's not what push notifications are for.  If friend wants to get notifications, friend must register from his device.  If you want to send friends messages, you need to use some other protocol.

Comment: can u suggest some other means

Comment: You could send him a meeting invitation with a built in-alarm.  Pretty much everything else requires a server running somewhere.

Comment: ok then will this invitation look like notification

Comment: yes it will (Assuming he has set to receive inviations as notifications), BUT - the invitation itself it not an alarm sound at that time, it needs to be accepted, and then at the predetermined time it will go off...  with a notification.

Comment: It might be simpler for you to just call him on the phone at the appropriate time :-).  Ask yourself-are you more interested in waking your friend up, or writing a fun application?

Comment: This might work - create a shared calendar (on google calendar for example).  He should subscribe to it on his phone - but you should update entries on it online (unless you want to wake up with him!).  This way the alarm will just go off, with a 'notification' on the screen, and he doesn't need to 'accept' it or anything.

Comment: ok we can use server but will this invitation automatically get saved in phone or user has to save the timing details manualy

Comment: all automatic.  I keep getting alarms for stuff my wife has added to our shared calendar.

Comment: can shared calender get integrated in alarm app

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a push notification which would require your friend to register their device. Then you would need to determine which device ID belongs to your friend.  A simpler solution I would suggest would be to simply use SMS notifications which would allow you to personalize to whichever phone number you wish.

```
-(IBAction) sendInAppSMS:(id) sender
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Hello! Time to get up!;
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

source: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/

NOTE: It might be more useful to use SMS because if an individual's phone is off they will get the SMS message once the phone is turned on. However if an individual's phone is off and they are sent a push notification it is not guaranteed that they will receive it. If it is required that they receive the messages, then push notifications may not be the best solution.